# InetAddress get IP inconsistency

Tags: java, timeout, ip, ip-address, inetaddress

I'm trying to go through a list of URL's and grab their IP but what I'm noticing is sometimes it will get hung up on a website and never move on and other times it will skip a bunch of websites. Does anyone know what's causing this?

```
for (String site : sites) {

    try {
        address = InetAddress.getByName(new URL(site).getHost()).getHostAddress();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    IPList.put(address, site);
    publish(site);

}
```

EDIT: I've narrowed the problem down to the publish method. It seems like it's finishing the for loop before it has a chance to publish everything and then it just stops...

EDIT2: Figured it out, small mistake on my end. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the URLs you were testing?

Comment: http://www.3dbrickpavingandnaturalstone.com/
http://www.320ranch.com/
http://a1carpetandtile.com/
http://www.adoberesort.com/
http://www.advancedlightandsound.com/
http://www.thealhonnaresort.com/
http://www.andersoncertified.com/
http://www.cabinsoftheblackhills.com/
http://www.banffcariboulodge.com/
http://www.rockymountainresort.com/
http://www.berrycreekcabins.com/
http://www.birchcliff.com/
http://www.blackbutteranch.com/
http://blueharborresort.com/
http://www.orcasislandboardwalk.com/
http://www.buffalocountyoutfitters.com/

Just a few

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
private ArrayList<String> ips = new ArrayList<String>();

for (String site : sites) {
try {
    address = InetAddress.getByName(new URL(site).getHost());
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
String ip = address.getHostAddress();
ips.add(ip);

}
```

Comment: EDIT: It worked one time through but when I ran it again I encountered  the same problem.

Comment: You mean it works when you ran the it the first time, and when you ran it again, you met the same problem?

Comment: Yeah but I figured it out, it was a problem in my process method. Thanks.